# In an Azure VM availability group with SQL Server, is there a guarantee the secondary server will not restart while data is synchronizing?

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2012, azure-virtual-machine

After creating an availability group, the system is running with Server1 as the primary and Server2 as the secondary. Data synchronisation is taking place from primary to secondary.

If Server1 fails, the retry policy opens a new connection to Server2, which becomes the new primary.

When Server1 is back up and running, data synchronising starts from Server2 to Server1. This is the data that was captured by Server2 while Server1 was down.

Is it guaranteed that Server2 will not be restarted by Azure updates while the recovery sync is in progress?

It seems to me that although server1 is "back up and running", the availability group is not yet in a state in which server2 can be restarted.

Our design is SQL server 2012 running on Azure VMs.

Comment: I will not be definite, but I think that if both server and up and running, Availability Group is considered "fine/full/whatever the state for this is". But on another note, I also don't think there is such behavior on Azure IaaS: `VM will be restarted by Azure updates`, or at least the chance this to happen in IaaS is very small - much smaller than for a PaaS setup.

Comment: Here is THE reading - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/igorpag/archive/2013/09/02/sql-server-2012-alwayson-availability-group-and-listener-in-azure-vms-notes-details-and-recommendations.aspx you shall go through, to find the answers to all (most of?) your questions regarding SQL Server 2012 Always On on Azure VM.

Comment: That's a great article. Unfortunately it doesn't answer my specific question. If the servers are synching after failover, does Azure categorise them as "up and running"? Eg, does Azure feel it can install Windows Updates and restart one of the SQL servers?